# How to achieve parallel processing in Weblogic 9

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, jdeveloper, weblogic9.x

Using JDeveloper 10, I am trying to make a parallel processing that means, in

```
step1: To process a workflow synchronously to response back.
Step2: Using the input provided during synchronous call in step 1 and making a call parallely to approach a back end process to update the same process in a delay with some updated information. The time delay is because the backend process will take some time to process. 
Constraint : This application request will be provided by multiple users.
```

Got an idea to use weblogic 9/OC4J server JMS support, where there is an internal support in JDeveloper 10 to use MDB and client to make an onMessage call to make it work parallely.
Please suggest any approaches or is it possbile to make JMS call

Answer (score -1):

There are Work Managers in Weblogic you can easly use to do that.

Of course nobody prevent you from starting your own parallel threads as in any other Java apps.

BTW: why did you ask about so old version of Weblogic?

Comment: In case of own parallel thread process needs to do some multithreading stuff to manage (or) any inbuilt supports available in WLS.
JDeveloper 10g doesn't supports above weblogic 9.x.

Comment: Use Eclipse or Net Beans and do not bother others with outdated tools - 10 years old. As I said there are Work Managers in Weblogic. Go and read about what is it and what is stand for.

Comment: ...and forget weblogic 9.x which is no longer supported. Use 12c instead.